# Functional equation on quaternions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $\Bbb H$ be the quaternions and $m:\Bbb H\to \Bbb R$ satisfy the multiplicative functional equation
$$
m(pq)=m(p)m(q)
$$
for all $p, q\in \Bbb H$.

How to represent $m$ in terms of multiplicative functions and exponential 
functions on $\Bbb R$?

For example, if $\Bbb H$ is replace by the the set of complex numbers $\Bbb C$, 
$m$ can be written 
$$
m(z)=m(|z|)E(\arg z)
$$
for all $z\in \Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$, where $E$ is an exponential function with period $2\pi$.

Comment: You can write a complex number $z$ as $|z| e^{i \arg z}$, and so $m(z) = m(|z|)m(e^{i \arg z}$, but that's different than saying $m(e^{i \arg z})$ is itself an exponential, no? In particular, m(z) = |z| is multiplicative.

Comment: Let $\arg z=\theta $. Then it means that $E$ is an exponential as a function of $\theta$.

Comment: @Chung.J Do you mean that $m$ maps to the multiplicative group $\mathbb R\backslash \{0\}$?

Comment: No! the case reduced to trivial result $m=1$.

Answer (score 0):

The quaternion group is finite, so for you to satisfy $m(pq) = m(p)m(q)$ then $m$ can necessarily only map to $\pm 1$.

Moreover, $m(-1) = m(i^2) = m(i)^2 =1$ because $(\pm 1)^2 = 1$.

Since $ijk = -1$ then $m(ijk) = 1$, so either $m$ is the trivial map, or it maps two of $i,j$ and $k$ to $-1$ and the other $1$. It seems that either of these gives well defined group homomorphisms.

In light of this, it doesn't seem to be that there is any canonical way of making the map you describe.

If I have misunderstood the question then do let me know.

Comment: I mean the quaternion group $\Bbb H=\{a+bi+cj+dk : a, b, c, d\in \Bbb R\}$.

Comment: Okay, well that isn't the quaternion group, which is defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group but the quaternions is how they are normally referred to, and they are an algebra over $\mathbb R$, as defined here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion

Comment: @Chung.J In that case, do you want your map to also be linear, i.e. so that $m(a+b) = m(a) + m(b)$?

Comment: @Chung.J It looks like an interesting problem, but it would be good to know what you actually mean...